# Why should I keep scanning the area?

Tags: orion-vault

If the game goes a while without clicking the "Scan Area" button, the UI changes colors and the area changes state (i.e. "safe" became "relaxed").  What are the different levels an area can become?  Does anything happen on those other levels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep scanning to keep the risk of pirates low.

The levels the area can be are:

1. Dangerous
2. Hazardous
3. Tense
4. Relaxed
5. Safe

From the game page:

> SCAN AREA – Keep scanning to stay out of trouble. Make sure you are in
>   a ‘safe’ area at all times…or else!

As the text implies, not scanning the area means you won't know about impending danger, and risk your ship.

It's a game feature that is trying to keep you aware of your surroundings and on edge. Just like you'd be looking for enemies on your radar if you were mining an asteroid belt in space, this is simulating that in the format the game uses.

The higher the danger in the zone, the more likely you are to be attacked by pirates. This is not game ending, but it will damage your ship, destroy drones and cost you significant repair fees. If you don't have enough funds to cover these repairs, the remainder will be added to your loan.